# how to understand - and := in bash?

Tags: bash

```
JOBS=${JOBS:="-j2"}

dir=${1-/usr/src}
```

What does `:=` and `-` mean here?

I can guess they serve as some kind of default , what's the difference then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`man bash` (the `Parameter Expansion` section) will answer these and related questions.

Excerpt:

```
   ${parameter:-word}
          Use Default Values.  If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted.  Otherwise, the value of parame‐
          ter is substituted.
   ${parameter:=word}
          Assign  Default  Values.   If  parameter  is  unset or null, the expansion of word is assigned to parameter.  The value of
          parameter is then substituted.  Positional parameters and special parameters may not be assigned to in this way.
   ${parameter:?word}
          Display Error if Null or Unset.  If parameter is null or unset, the expansion of word (or a message to that effect if word
          is  not present) is written to the standard error and the shell, if it is not interactive, exits.  Otherwise, the value of
          parameter is substituted.
   ${parameter:+word}
          Use Alternate Value.  If parameter is null or unset, nothing is substituted, otherwise the expansion of  word  is  substi‐
          tuted.
```

Comment: Also see the [Shell Command Language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02) documentation (specifically section 2.6.2 "Parameter Expansion") for the more general case.

Comment: Even though this is not documented, they work the same for me.

Answer (score 3):

For `:=` (and the related `=`), you can use the built-in ':' command to just evaluate the parameter without having to assign it to itself:

```
# Set JOBS=-j2 if JOBS is not set or equal to ""
: ${JOBS:='-j2'}

# Set JOBS=-j2 if JOBS is not set. Don't change if JOBS is already set to ""
: ${JOBS='-j2'}
```

For `:-` and `-`, don't change the value of the variable; just use the second value in its place:

```
# Set dir to /usr/src if $1 is not set, but don't set $1 itself
dir=${1-/usr/src}

# Set dir to /usr/src if $1 is not set or set to "", but don't set or change $1
dir=${1:-/usr/src}
```